# Error in cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport when change array of items

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a list of items (products) inside a virtual scroll, the problem occurs when I change the items of array.

**For example:**

Initially I have 100 items in the scroll.

Then I run a function "reloadItems()" **that change the 100 items to 4 items.**

If I previously ran the scroll down, it's works fine.

Otherwise, the virtual scroll only shows the items visible in the view and doesn't show the other items ( in my case it shows only 2 items instead of 4)

As you can see in the next image the bottom of the scroll does not display any products.

[image]

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" style="min-height: calc(80% - 105px);" class="example-viewport"
    [hidden]="!hasProductsInStock" autosize minBufferPx="600" maxBufferPx="800">
       <div *cdkVirtualFor="let p of dataSource" class="example-item">
           <mat-card class="example-card mat-elevation-z5">
               <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
                   <img mat-card-image src="{{ '/api/products/' + p.id + '/image' }}" alt="" style="width: 49%;" />
               </div>
               <mat-card-content>
                   <div class="txt_name">
                       {{ p.name }}
                   </div>
                   <div class="price_and_cant">
                       <div class="price">
                           <b>$ {{ p.price }}</b>
                       </div>
                       <div class="div_add_remove">
                           <i>remove</i>
                           <div><span>{{ getProductAmount(p.id) }}</span>
                           </div>
                           <i>add</i>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </mat-card-content>
           </mat-card>
       </div>
   </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

CSS

```
.example-viewport {
  min-height: calc(97% - 105px);
}
```

I want to show all the items, when I change the array from 100 items to 4 items I need the scroll to show 4 items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the problem was that i set the attribute **autosize** and generated the wrong behavior.